# Diferentiate user not found from wrong credentials

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

When calling `loginWithPassword` I receive an error with code 403 in both cases: when the user doesn't exist and when the password is wrong. I know that theirs messages/reasons  are different, but I think that comparing with string is not a good practice. Is there a different way of differentiating these cases?
**UPDATE** Using `accounts-password`

Comment: Just a guess, but the framework probably gives the same response because if you tell folks the password is wrong, they can use the difference between bad login and bad password to discover valid users of the site.

Comment: How did you handle this case eventually?

Answer (score 0):

No real way of differentiating other than checking the error description string (that is what it is for).

You can always implement your own mechanism server-side (e.g, a method), but the default one sends a numeric error code (normally corresponding to the HTTP code - in this case, [403 forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)), accompanied by a string.

They [have not changed recently](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blame/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js) and it is fairly safe to depend on them, especially if it is not something mission-critical.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a method that checks for the existence of a user and then call that after a failed login attempt. If the user exists then you can display a bad password warning.

You could even check existence before the password is typed and put a green checkmark next to the username field if the user is found or a red X otherwise.

There are many ways to do this.